# Configuring ASP.NET project to IISExpress 10.0

Tags: asp.net, web-config, iis-express

I have an ASP.NET app built.  I am looking to deploy it to IISExpress.  I have IIS Express 10.0 and VS2015 on Windows 10 OS.  When I try to run my app I get the following error. "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:773".  To me it sounds like I do not have it hooked up to a web server (please correct if I'm wrong about this).

So, I did some research here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis and a few other sites and found some info on what I need to do to add a site to IISExpress.

1. I moved my project into /wwwroot folder.
2. I opened IIS Manager and right-clicked on "Sites" folder and selected "Add Website".
3. I get the following popup [image]
4. Notice in the highlighted area I am missing other fields such as "Port", "IP Address" and "Port Name" like this: [image]
5. I went ahead and entered in my Site Name, Physical path to the wwwroot project, set my connection credentials and tested which both Authorized and Authenticated passed.
6. However, unless I set the bindings I cannot add the website, but as mentioned above I am missing fields to make that happen. I suppose this is issue #1?

Comment: IIS Manager does not work for IIS Express. Port 773 requires administrator permissions.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you.